# Maxmimum Y axis value for a chart

Tags: analysis

I would like to draw **Histogram** chart comparing two values, 1) BE Candidates, 2) MCA Candidates. 
The values pairs example.

1. BE Candidates (5) - MCA Candidates (100)
2. BE Candidates (500) - MCA Candidates (20)
3. BE Candidates (15) - MCA Candidates (16)
4. BE Candidates (3) - MCA Candidates (22)

I would like to find a maximum Y axis value based on BE Candidates and MCA candidates count. Is there any calculation to find the maximum value to be set, so that the difference between those two values will be better visible?

Please advice, Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum needs to be at least 500 so you can get all the data on.  Any higher and you lose resolution, so 500 (or maybe just a little higher so the bar stops) it is.  You are right that it will be hard to see the smaller values then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy, i need some mathematical calculation to compute the value. Do you have one based on provided values? Charts used to do this. If you give all values lesser than 10, it will take 10 as maximum suppose. If we give 1, 400, 200, 150, it may take 400 or more as maximum. I need a formula to find this. Please advice, Thank you.

Comment: @ParamasivanSamuttiram:  You can just take the max and min of your data.  Alternately, you can round it up to the next power of 10, or to the next 1,2, or 5 times a power of 10.  The hard part is deciding clearly what you want-once that is in place it can be turned into a formula.

Comment: Yes, i can make it as next power of 10, thanks for the idea!